# Pointing SSL Enabled URL at Single WordPress Page

Tags: ssl, dns

## Synopsis

So, for this example, assume that we have https://example.org hosted on WP Engine. Everything works fine, nothing custom here in regards to the domain mapping.

https://example2.org is a separate URL owned by the same client and they would like to have this URL point to a page on the Example website:

https://example2.org shows content from https://example.org/subpage while masking the URL as https://example2.org. I have had success in doing this without the SSL but can't seem to figure out how to enforce SSL on this URL. Anytime I input HTTPS on .htaccess for the rewrite, the page automatically redirects to the home page for https://example.org. Is there something obvious here I'm missing? I suspect the culprit lies in security settings for multiple certificates, but I'm not sure.

**[ Update ]**

As it turns out, non-www is working fine with the SSL, but the www- version of the URL is redirecting this to the original URL home page. Any ideas on what could be the culprit here?

Thanks again!